# ¿Como configurar tareas periódicas dinamicamente en celery con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, rabbit-mq

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Python, Celery y RabbitMq, con múltiples EC2 de Amazon AWS.

Esto es mi arquitectura:
Donde cada EC2.. contiene varios workers con concurrencia según la cantidad de recursos de hardware, y todos se conectan al EC2-Master vía RabbitMq.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo el procesamiento distribuido lo hace bien a nivel de Instancias.
y tengo un proceso de tareas periódicas que tome como referencia: :http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html  con un tiempo estático así:

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks_url(sender, **kwargs):

    allSites = Site.getAllSites()
    groupUrls = []

    if len(allSites)>=40:
        groups = 40
    else:
        groups = len(allSites)

    groupSites = numpy.array_split(allSites, groups)

    for group in groupSites:
        urls = []
        for site in group:
            urls.append({'url': site.t_websit_url, 'status_tracking': site.b_status_tracking})
        groupUrls.append(urls)
    for url in groupUrls:
        # ejecuto cada 10 min, tarea periodica
        sender.add_periodic_task(600, task_url.s(url), expires=60)
        print("EJECUTANDO TAREA PERIÓDICA CON CELERY..!")
```

Esto funciona muy bien como tarea periódica cada 10 min; pero mi gran problema ocurre cuando el procesamiento demora más de 10 min o menos con lo cual generalmente se sobrecarga de procesos hasta que en un punto acaba de llenarse la memoria de las instancias, osea se genera una **SOBRECARGA**, y lo que quiero es optimizar el tiempo..
El procesamiento por cada ciclo, su duración en muy variante, puede demorar entre 5 a 40 min. por ello requiero ejecutar la tarea periódica de forma **dinámica**, es decir, cuando todo el procesamiento actual haya finalizada en todos los workers, que empiece recién el siguiente bloque como tarea periódica.
Como se podría determinar que todos los procesos hayan terminado en celery y empezar el siguiente bloque..? o alguna forma de hacer eficiente este proceso?.
Me refiero al **bloque** a la nueva consulta que hago a la base de datos que alimenta otro proceso.
Gracias